# Find maximum number of strings.

Tags: combinatorics, finite-automata

Given a `Finite Automata` with fix number of input symbols $k$. What is the maximum number of strings of maximum length $n$ it can accept.

How to think about the problem and progress in the right direction?

Comment: Do you know how to count the number of strings with length exactly $m$ using a $k$ letter alphabet?

Comment: Why down-voted? strange!

Comment: @TravisJ, its $k^m$?

Comment: Yes, $k^m$... what values of $m$ might occur?  Probably all values of $m$ for $0\leq m\leq n$ (your max length).  If you add together the number of strings of length 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., $n$ you'll count what you want.

Comment: Probably down-voted because your question shows no work on your part.  That is expected here (to show your own work/attempt and to provide context).

Comment: I am amazed! why there is no culture of telling newbies before being down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are constructing a string of length exactly $n_0$ with $k$ distinct symbols which may each be used multiple times, then on place $1$ in the string you have $k$ choices. As each symbol is useable multiple times, you have $k$ choices also for place 2 in the string, and so on. Thus you have $k^{n_0}$ number of strings of size $n_0$. Now to get the strings of $max$ length, you have to sum all of the possible lengths $n_0$.

$\Sigma_{i=0}^n k^i$

Which is a geometric sum.

Comment: I checked the answer was $1 + k + k^2 + ... + k^n$. Why there is extra one? due to empty string?

Comment: The index should start from $i=0$...

Comment: ah, right the empty string should be included. I've edited the answer so that it starts on $0$.